# Browsers security in fullscreen players

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, opera

This question is just something that I want to know (nothing is broken in code *yay*)

In the most browsers going to fullscreen causes the security adnotation coming (in most cases) from the top of the display.

I can not understand why it is suspicous, could you share your knowledge about why it is less secure to view (fe) the video in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser chrome is a trusted security indicator, and full-screen mode hides that indicator.

If a page could enter full-screen mode without the browser notifying the user, a malicious page could enter full-screen mode, draw Chrome's address bar, and look exactly like a Google login page to trick the user into giving their password.